# Search function not working - Cakephp

Tags: cakephp, search

I'm using this action to search for a User name

It's working fine on my User Table

but when I tried to do the same on Contact Table 
I'm getting the url but it's not retrieving the result

ContactController.php

```
 public function index()
{
  $search = $this->request->query('search');
    if(!empty($search)){
        $this->paginate = [
            'conditions' =>['Contacts.name LIKE '=>'%'.$search. '%']

        ];
    }    
  $this->paginate = [
        'contain' => ['Users', 'Contacts', 'SourceProspects', 'Status', 'Secteurs', 'Products']
    ];
    $contacts = $this->paginate($this->Contacts);
    $this->set(compact('contacts'));
    $this->set('_serialize', ['contacts']);  

}
```

index.ctp

```
 <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-12 form-group top_search">
              <div class="input-group">

                <span class="input-group-btn">
                    <?= $this->Form->create("",['type'=>'get']) ?>
                    <?= $this->Form->control('search', ['default'=>$this->request->getQuery('search'),'class'=>'form-control','placeholder'=>'Search For Name'
                  ]); ?>
                    <button class="btn btn-default ">Go!</button>
                    <?= $this->Form->end() ?>
                                </span>
                </div>
                </div>
```

What am I missing ?

Comment: what is exactly your problem? A blank page? An empty recordset? Do you ahve debug mode enabled? Do you see a query been executed? Please add more information

Comment: My problem it's not showing the result needed its showing all data from table 
localhost/intellix/contacts?search=zak
I tried debug here $search = $this->request->query('search'); it does showing the result zak but not in my table view (Redirect) it keep displaying all array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you, you were right 
I Fixed by adding else

```
 public function index()
  {
     $search = $this->request->query('search');

    if(!empty($search)){
        $this->paginate = [
            'conditions' =>['Contacts.name LIKE '=>'%'.$search. '%']

        ];
    }else{

    $this->paginate = array(
        'limit' => 4 );
      [
    'contain' => ['Users', 'Contacts', 'SourceProspects', 'Status', 'Secteurs', 
'Products']

    ];
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

you are reassigning the pagination array (I'm pretty sure there is a similar question but I can't find it now)

in fact when you do

```
$this->paginate = [
    'contain' => [...]
];
```

the value of $this->paginate is being reassigned

the following should work

```
 $this->paginate = [
    'contain' => [/* your tables here */]
];

if(!empty($search)) {
    $this->paginate['conditions'] =>['Contacts.name LIKE '=>'%'.$search. '%']
}
```

But you can improve your code:

- `$this->request->query('search');` is deprecated, use `getQuery()`
- no need to use `'default'=>$this->request->getQuery('search')` in your view. The FormHelper does it for you if you use `$this->Form->create(null, ['valueSources' => 'query']);` This tells the formHelper to use query values to fill the controls value
- finally consider using friendsofcake/search plugin that does all the job